# Why to use __setattr__ in python?

Tags: python, setter

I don't know for why using `__setattr__` instead simple referencing like `x.a=1`.

I understand this example:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = 0
        self.height = 0


x=Rectangle()
x.width=20
x.__setattr__('height',30)
setattr(x,'width',99)
```

but don't get why using code depending on string ('height').

Could you explain me what are advantages of `__setattr__` ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You don't call it yourself. Period. If you need to use a string because you don't know the name beforehand (*very* bad idea in 99% of all cases where one might think they need this, nearly always a dict or list is a better/saner choice), you use the built-in `setattr` function.

However, it is called for you - when you do `a.x = ...`, that's done as `a.__setattr__('x', ...)` (this is propably an oversimplification). And some objects overload it to allow some trickery, e.g. to emulate immutability. [See the documentation of "special methods".](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__)

Answer (score 18):

`__setattr__` is a class method that is called by `setattr` builtin method. That is, if `__setattr__` is defined in given class. Most often you do not declare your own version of `__setattr__` so I assume you are asking of what use is the `setattr` method.

Suppose you have a var with the name of the attribute you want to set instead of just knowing the name:

```
class A(object):
    def doSth(self, name, val):
        setattr(self, name, val)
```

impossible to do with `self.name = val`

Also, a common usage is with keyword args:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

Comment: Does the latter construct have any advance over `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)`?

Comment: Yes it does. Using `setattr` goes through custom `__setattr__` if defined. Please note that custom `__setattr__` doesn't have to touch `__dict__` at all (it's common to use `__setattr__` for some dynamic attribute lookup, proxy etc.).

Answer (score 8):

I can envision an application where, for example, you override `__setattr__` and `__getattr__` to provide object-like access to some other data structure that isn't kept in memory.  For example, you could create an object where `foo.CustomerName = "John"` updated the `CustomerName` column in a database row pointed to by `foo` to contain the value `"John"`. I.e., `foo.__setattr__` would use the attribute name and value to construct a command to update a database on disk. I'd hate to have to write such a thing, but it would be possible.

Comment: This is exactly how I've used `__setattr__` in the past.  It's not for the feint of heart, and I recommend rigorous testing (even `test-driven development`) to anyone who needs this sort of special functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `__xxx__` are operator overloading methods of the class and as such should only be used in special situations and not in cases as in your example.

For example, `__setattr__` intercepts all attribute assignments and can be used to change the behaviour of your class when a value is assigned to an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The first use of `__setattr__` is to be overwritten in a class definition.

```
class Foo ( object ) :

    def __init__ ( self ) :
        self.x = 'looser'

    def __setattr__ ( self, name, value ) :
        if name == 'x' :
            print( 'Hello, {} !'.format( value ) )
            self.x = value
```

Problem, `Foo()` will print an infinite sequence of :

```
'Hello, looser !'
```

There comes the second use which is that, when you're doing that, you can call **setattr** from the parent class (`object` by default) to avoid infite recursion :

```
class Foo ( object ) :

    def __setattr__ ( self, name, value ) :
        self.bar( name, value )
        object.__setattr__( self, name, value )

    def bar ( self, name, value ) :
        print( 'Setting {} to {}.'.format( name, value ) )
```

And therefore :

```
f = Foo()

>> 'Hello, winner !'

f.x

>> 'winner'
```

Answer (score 1):

the `__setattr__` can be used to reflection, where an propperty on the object Rectangle can be created at runtime, there are more about it on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_science%29

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self):
        #... code ...

x = Rectangle()
#x.__setattr__('newProperty',30)      Edited after comment
setattr(x, 'newProperty', 30)
print x.newProperty #>>> 30
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that that's a horrible idea for most puposes (notable exception: some metaprogramming): Why not just use the built-in `setattr`?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Name(object):
    pass

obj=Name()

#just i have created object two way 
#first

obj.a="first"
print obj.a

#answer= "first"
#second

obj.__setattr__('b','second')
print obj.a
#answer= "second"
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. I would recommend you to provide more details on how this code is helping the issue.