# Explain the use of __setattr__

Tags: python

Can you please explain the use of the `__setattr__` method in the below code :

```
class Human(object):
    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        if name == 'gender':
            if value in ('male', 'female'):
                self.gender = value
            else :
                raise AttributeError('Gender can only be Male or Female')

 h = Human()
h.name = 'Mary'
h.gender = 'female'
print h.gender
```

Comment: What precisely don't you understand? Have you tried employing e.g. `print` to investigate the confusing behaviour? Read the Python documentation regarding that *"magic"* method?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755023/why-to-use-setattr-in-python

Comment: It makes this class unusable. For value checking use properties.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `__setattr__()` function is making a validation that while assigning the value of `self.gender`, it's value should be only between `male` and `female`. In case of any other value, it will raise `AttributeError` exception.

*Note:* In your `__setattr__()` function, there is no call to `super` of `__setattr__`, and hence this function is not actually updating the properties of class. You should add below line in your `__setattr__()` in order to make it work:

```
super(Human, self).__setattr__(name, value)
```

---

**Overview about [`.__setattr__(self, name, value)`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__)**:

Whenever you assign any value to the property of the class, `__setattr__(self, name, value)` function is called where `name` is the property of `class` and `value` is the new value to be assigned. Below is the sample code to demonstrate that:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...         self.x = x
...         self.y = y
...     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
...         print 'In Set Attr for: ', name, ', ', value
...         super(MyClass, self).__setattr__(name, value)
...
...
>>> my_object = MyClass(1, 2)
In Set Attr for:  x, 1
In Set Attr for:  y, 2
>>> my_object.x = 10  # <-- Called while assigning value x
In Set Attr for:  x, 10
```